# Как корректно передать значение

Tags: javascript, php, функции

День добрый, что-то понять не могу в чем проблема.
Через php передаю функцию

```
$k = 'a'.$k.$drot;
echo "<td><div id='".'a'.$k.$drot."' onclick=func(".$k.") class='brd'>;
echo "</div></td>";
```

функцию объявляю через

```
function  func(kok) {
 document.getElementById(kok).style.background = 'red'; 
 console.log(kok);
}
```

Когда запускаю и нажимаю на требуемый элемент мне пишет:

```
TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null
```

В чем моя ошибка? Ведь по идее должно вывести значение переданной в функцию переменной kok и сменить цвет в элементе.

Начал только недавно учить js, просмотрел кучи сайтов, но так и не понял в чем проблема. Сама передаваемая переменная kok в массиве изменяется и каждый раз передается в функцию новая. Переменная $k всегда(!!!) имеет какое-то значение.

Comment: Надо смотреть есть ли такой id. Собссн всё. Уверен проблема тут: `id='".'a'.$k.$drot."'`

Answer (score 1):

Вот такой код:

```
$k = 1;
$drot = 2;
$k = 'a'.$k.$drot;
echo "<td><div id='".'a'.$k.$drot."' onclick=func(".$k.") class='brd'>";
echo "</div></td>";
```

выводит:

```
<td><div id='aa122' onclick=func(a12) class='brd'></div></td>
              ^------ разные -----^
```

Думаю выводы вы сделаете сами, где вы делаете лишнюю конкатенацию

Comment: У меня есть цикл в котором переменные $k и $drot увеличивается на 1 за 1 иттерацию
Даже если я тыкаю все это в $wuf = 'a'.$k.$drot; и потом $wuf ставлю в оба места - пишет тоже самое

Comment: Может у меня какая-то ошибка в синтаксисе передачи значений в функцию? или еще что-то. Т.к. по сути переменная $wuf это хэш другого значения

Comment: @Mastas в первом `echo` в конце нет двойных ковычек. Остальное - без понятия. Я не IDE.  В чем проблема я вам сказал. неправильный идентификатор. Это уже ваше дело как его исправить

Answer (score 0):

В общем разобрался в чем проблема. Не в неправильном идентификаторе как отметил товарищ Сергей выше, а в том что передаваемое в функцию значение не было заранее определено. 
Было:

```
$x = 'A'.$k.$drot;
```

Решило проблему:

```
$x = '';
$x = 'A'.$k.$drot;
```

Не знаю почему, но после этого стало нормально видить переменную.